# Integration test all possibilities within one test case

Tags: grails, integration-testing, assert

I am running a test to see if an email is valid - valid as in not in use within the application by another user.

I want to show when a valid email is entered, that assert true hold, and when an invalid email is entered, that assert false holds.

My code is as follows:

```
class UserControllerIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase{

@Before
void setUp() {
    // Setup logic here
}

@After
void tearDown() {
    // Tear down logic here
}

@Test
void testValidateEmail() {

    def userController = new UserController()

    userController.params.email = "ddewdd@a.com"
    userController.validateEmail()

    assertEquals "true", userController.response.contentAsString

    userController.params.email = "a@a.com"
    userController.validateEmail()

    assertEquals "false", userController.response.contentAsString

 }
```

}

my `validateEmail()` in my controller looks like :

```
def validateEmail()
{
    def valid = false

    if(params.email != null && params.email != "")
    {
        //count how many users have this email - ignore case            
        if (User.countByEmailIlike(params.email) == 0)
        {
            valid = true
        }
    }

    render valid 
}
```

but I am getting an error as follows :

```
    Failure:  testValidateEmail(uk.co.litecollab.UserControllerIntegrationTests)
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[]false> but was:<[true]false>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:125)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at uk.co.litecollab.UserControllerIntegrationTests.testValidateEmail(UserControllerIntegrationTests.groovy:36)
```

it seems to be failing on the second assertion

when I run the two assertions individually, they both pass, so I know the data in the assertion statements are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does `validateEmail()` look like in the `controller`?

Comment: Try userController.response.reset() before calling the second time.